# Simple VB, handling many buttons

Tags: vb.net, events, button, event-handling

In my VB solution I have a lot of buttons arranged in a grid. When the program is loaded one of the buttons is randomly set to be the right one (You have to click that one to win). Can anybody point my in the right direction? Because there must be a better way than manually coding every single button, and creating an event handler for every single button.

You don't have to give me a working example, just an overall idea of how this is done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to arrange the buttons in a grid, either use the TableLayoutPanel or add the buttons directly to the form and calculate their positions. The `TableLayoutPanel` is useful if you want to arrange the buttons automatically when the form resizes, otherwise adding the buttons directly seems easier to me.

Add the buttons to an array defined at form level to make them easily accessible

```
Public Const NColumns As Integer = 5, NRows As Integer = 4

Private buttons As Button(,) = New Button(NColumns - 1, NRows - 1) {}
```

You can add the buttons easily in loops

```
For ix As Integer = 0 To NColumns - 1
    For iy As Integer = 0 To NRows - 1
        Dim btn = New Button()
        btn.Text = String.Format("{0:d2}{1:d2}", ix, iy)
        btn.Location = New Point(leftMargin + ix * xDistance,
                                 topMargin + iy * yDistance)
        btn.Size = New Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight)
        AddHandler btn.Click, Addressof Button_Clicked
        buttons(ix, iy) = btn
        Controls.Add(btn)   
    Next
Next
```

You can determine the winning button with a random generator. Define it as form member, not as local variable.

```
Private randomGenrator As System.Random = New System.Random()
```

Determine the coordinates

```
Dim xWins = randomGenrator.Next(NColumns) 'Returns a number between 0 and NColumns-1
Dim yWins = randomGenrator.Next(NRows)
```

The click handler looks like this

```
Private Sub Button Button_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If sender = buttons(xWins, yWins) Then
       'You win
    Else
       'You loose
    End
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you said you want a grid of buttons, so you have to have a `FlowLayoutPanel` control in your form in order to let the buttons you want to add, to be arranged automatically.
Second, you have to make use of a for loop, r any kind of look, in order to add the buttons to be added to previously added 'FlowLayoutPanel'.
    class Answers
        Dim strAnswerText as string
        Dim AnswerFlag as Boolean
    End Class

```
Sub LoadForm(byval a_Answers as Answer())        
    Dim i as Integer = 0
    Dim b as Button 
    For(i=0;i<NUM_OF_BUTTONS;i++)
       b = New Button()
       b.Text = "Choice -" & i & "- " & a_Answers(i).strAnswerText 
       b.Tag = a_Answers(i).AnswerFlag

       'Supposing that the FlowLayoutPanel control name is fl
       AddHandler b.Click, Addressof Clicked
       fl.controls.Add(b)   
    End For 
End Sub

Sub Button Clicked(sender as object, e as EventArgs)
    if sender.Tag = True
       'True answer
    else
       'Wrong answer
    end if

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't all the buttons get the 'True' tag this way?

Comment: yes you are right, you have to get around this one, like, you have to give the right answer number as an argument. like 'LoadForm( byval rightanswer as integer)', and so ...